# Android: How to make focus blinking after clicking button

Tags: android, selector

i want to make a button on that click event focus effect keeps on blinking  for few seconds.

how to do?

please help me..

Comment: What do you mean by `keeps on blinking`?

Comment: use array of images and set that one.

Comment: hii iturki keeps on blinking means , when we click on button we get orange color after click effect , i want that effect keep on blin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should investivate the *Android Animation Framework*, great blog post here: (http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/)

You could easily implement the blinking by adjusting the alpha (transparency) value of the object.

Comment: hii iturki keeps on blinking means , when we click on button we get orange color after click effect , i want that effect keep on blin

Comment: hi hypnos, i want to make focus blinking not the button blinking

Comment: @Mitt from your explanation I understood the focus would be just a object around the button, which can also be thus animated. You would also need to disable the default android button focus.